# Display Current Directory - Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

Is there a way to display the current directory you're in on the page using classic asp?
I used to do it using PHP but I've had a browse around various forums and not found a working way to do it in classic ASP.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
Applications
  MainMenu
    default.asp
    pages
      page1.inc
      page2.inc
  Orders
    default.asp
    pages
      page1.inc
      page2.inc
  Application
    default.asp
    pages
      page1.inc
      page2.inc
```

When I'm in any of the different sections I'd like to display the directory name in the page header.

Comment: `response.write(Server.MapPath("."))` will give you the path to the current page

Comment: I need it to only show the directory. `Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO"))` This shows me everything including the file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had to go old school on this one.

```
A = Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")
B = split(A,"/")
response.write (B(ubound(B)-1))
```

A loads server variable of the full path including the file name.
B spits this by the "/"
And finally the last directory name is shown with the (B(ubound(B)-1)) where ubound finds the count of array elements and then selects the next to last result.

Comment: Perfect! That  works perfectly. I'd kinda lost hope in this as I've asked all over the place!

Branching off from this, is there a way for it to display only the file name without the file type extension?

Comment: @user4210292 `Response.Write Split((B(UBound(B) -1))), ".")(0)` Use the `.` in the extension to split the filename into array elements, the filename will be the first element in the array.

Comment: @user4210292 Or a safer method that only ever gets the last `.` in a filename would be `Response.Write Right((B(UBound(B) -1)), (Len((B(UBound(B) -1))) - InStrRev((B(UBound(B) -1)), ".", -1, 1)))`

Comment: This does not work from within include files or `Server.Execute(...)` files, which may be required for certain operations.  It will give the parent ASP file information instead.